# Is NoSQL worth in my case

Tags: mysql, json, database, nosql

I have to design a database in order to make reporting. Data is varied (from accounts to logs or social media posts). The volume is about 1 million lines per day.

In my mind :

**SQL pros :**

- The main goal for user is to make this kind of request : Number of user having a skype account and more than 4Go of storage. It involves a lot of joins and structural database is more coherent in this case.
- SQL database is enough powerfull for this volume
- To store identity linked to account, I think SQL structure is more suitable.

**NoSQL pros :**

- JSON format is an asset because data source are provided by multivalued document and some fields can be removed/added easily.
- The database is "open", so new service can be added to the database. It involves more volume, not known data.(nosql scalability)
- Some tools (like kibana / elastic search) seems to be compliant with nosql technologies.

It is difficult to me to decide, on one hand it seems to be difficult to put all identity (+ account + orders + other informations ) in one document, on the other once this problem is solved it seems powerful and interesting (Json, scalability...).

I'll take any advice ;)

Comment: Answers to such a question will tend to reflect personal preference.  Even if there would be a clear "that one", such a decision could not be made without *a lot* more details (e.g.: how exactly does "Number of user having a skype account and more than 4Go of storage" will be done on a dataset containing data "from accounts to logs or social media posts"). Additionally, "NoSQL" is very unspecific - there's a wide range of NoSQL products, some of which can be used like a normal relational database, including integrity, joins and even acid, while MySQL can use json too (at least to some degree).

Comment: Elasticsearch can load data from JDBC data sources too. That's not a reason to use NoSQL (whatever that means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a big topic
However my 2 cents here to consider the following:

- Database Integrity: If you have to guarantee db integrity at all times, then consider SQL
- Resources: If you're entending to make use of cloud wide distrubuted computing and storage, then consider NoSQL

Afterall, it does not have to be one or the other. You can also consider an architecture which has a mix of both. Order processing/accounting/e-commerce tend to fit to SQL. While blogs and social media posts fit NoSQL
Your specific "main goal" can be acheived using SQL and NoSQL with proper choice of tools and design

NoSQL has many flavours too, and not as standardized as SQL. If you're considering NoSQL, you have another deep research to do - which best fits your business scenarios

Further, consider your organization's capabilities, and stratigic direction!